# Usage of とも in a sentence

Tags: meaning, usage

> だが、そんな永久とも思われた戦乱は、唐突にその幕を閉じる

How is とも being used here? I'm not exactly sure on the specific answer and my translation came out to be "But the war they thought that would continue for eternity suddenly came to an end."

Comment: と: quotative particle. も: non-unique topic marker. Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38787  
https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33764  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15892

Comment: ah, makes sense now, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Without the context in which とも is used, I am not sure what kind of special meaning this とも has. And I have learned from the previous answer that the と is the case particle as a quotative marker, and the も is the binding particle. This convincing explanation leads me to say that there must be some other alternatives to the thing(s) previously mentioned. For example, in this case, some thought that the war would continue only for some years, or they thought that five years ago the war would come to an end soon. But, it seems to me, this may not be too much emphasized because も in とも has no strong meaning of binding or adding in some contexts. So it could be said that your translation is all right without special reference to とも.